# How to write *.pc files for pkg-config on Windows?

Tags: windows, gtk, mingw, pkg-config

I've recently downloaded the gtk+ all-in-one bundle downloaded from the [GTK+ website](http://www.gtk.org/download-windows.html), which works fine and allows me to build gtk+ applications on Windows using the MinGW compiler.

However, when now looking at the *.pc files for pkg-config in lib/pkgconfig, I noticed something weird. Here's how the beginning of glib-2.0 looks like:

```
prefix=c:/devel/target/059c48de6b739307c37648aba3005b29
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib
includedir=${prefix}/include
```

My gtk+ folder resides on a different drive than C:\ and I don't have a C:\devel folder at all. So what does this prefix stand for? What prefix would I use if I decided to write a *.pc file for easily linking my own application?

Surprisingly enough, *using* pkg-config works as expected and returns the correct path the libraries and headers inside the gtk+ folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The version of pkg-config that comes with the all in one package basically ignores the prefix. It knows to look in ../lib/pkgconfig for the pkg-config files. You don't need to do anything special for your pkgconfig files other than either put them in that pkgconfig directory, *or* set some environment variables so pkg-config knows where to look for your *.pc files.

Comment: Seems like you're absolutely right - those hash-like paths really confused me. Now works by simply placing my pc files in the same folder as the other ones ;)

Comment: Can you be a little more precise? What is the default directory pkg-config looks for pc files? What is the "some" environment variables name?